# pandas astype str formatting

Tags: python, pandas, casting, type-conversion

I have a column in a csv I am reading in with pandas that contains years. Because some of the columns are missing they get NAN and the type of the column is float.

I convert the row to string to do some concatenation but instead of getting 2013 I get 2013.0

I fixed this by doing astype(int).astype(str) instead of just astype(str) But feel this may be wasteful doing double conversions like this.

What is the most efficient way to convert a float dtype column into a string dropping any decimal points that may occur(or rounding either way is fine.)

Comment: The decimal point is just a display issue, is there a reason it's a problem, you'll lose the ability to perform arithmetic calculations on a numeric type if you change it to str

Comment: yes I am parsing school years and need to transform 2013 for example to "2013 - 2014" but it is turning out "2013.0 - 2014.0"

Comment: How will you treat missing years then?

Comment: those rows are removed between me reading the file and runing this operation.

Comment: If you remove those rows then you should be able to convert to int or str without the decimal point, unless you have other issues with your data